# correct order: Bigger house than or house bigger than

Tags: adjectives, comparisons

Which one(s) of the following sentences is(are) correct:

Example 1:

1. I need a bigger house than my old house.
2. I need a house that is bigger than my old house.
3. I need a house bigger than my old house.

Example 2:

4. I need an older volunteer than me.
5. I need a volunteer that is older than me.
6. I need a volunteer older than me.

Are there any rules for choosing one of the following orders when using comparative adjective:

'adj-er + (phrase) + than + (phrase)' or '(phrase) + adj-er + than + (phrase)'

Comment: Apart from replacing "that" with "who" in number 5 I can see nothing I would change  in any of your examples. Why do you think that some of them may be incorrect?

Comment: Okay. That is what I wanted to know. I thought 3,6 sounded wrong or ungrammatical.

Comment: 3 and 6 are versions of 2 and 5 respectively, 3 omits the phrase "that is" and 6 omits "who is" but the omitted phrases are understood by implication. This sort of omission is quite common in English and is perfectly acceptable.